# Cassandra how to add values in a single row on every hit

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In this table application will feed us with the below data and it will be incremental as and when we will receive updates on the status . So initially table will look like the below as shown:-

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      ID       |  Total count  | Failed count  | Success count |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       1       |      30       |      10       |      20       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Now let’s assume total 30 messages are pushed now out of which 10 Failed and 20 Success  as shown above.Now again application is run and values changed . Now total 20 new records came in out of which all are success. This should be updated in the same row .

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      ID       |  Total count  | Failed count  | Success count |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       1       |      50       |      10       |      40       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Is it feasible in Cassandra DB using Counter data type?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use counter tables in your case. 
Let's assume table structure like :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE Test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };

CREATE TABLE data (
    id int,
    data string,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE counters (
    id int,
    total_count counter,
    failed_count counter,
    success_coutn counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can increment counters by running queries like :

```
UPDATE counters
SET total_count = total_count + 1,
success_count = success_count + 1
WHERE id= 1;
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Also wanted to ask you that in our case we are expecting a huge update every second,like 6000/7000 transactions per second. Will it be feasible with the use of counters or there are any other optimization parameters to be tweaked to achieve this.

Comment: Write performance on cassandra depends on the number of nodes you have and the consistency level (CL) used and the replication factor. This link may help you http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters. You can enable and configure counters cache in your cassandra.yml to improve read/write performance on counters.